# Tray Icons in Unity in 13.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.04, system-tray

In Ubuntu 13.04 there is no Tray Icon and Whiteliting is removed.
I Installed Gnome 3.8 but there is no tray there too!!
How can I get tray icons back (for applications that put icon in tray like Vuze,Truecrypt,... & have no Indicator) in Unity ?
e.g. a wrapper App Indicator that show old applications icons?
Thanks

Comment: Seth's answer does actually work, although in my case it needed an "apt-get install update" and "apt-get install upgrade" to prevent the "No such schema"-error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read about this today in this article [How To Get The Sysray Whitelist Back in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html). 

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want, I think the code below solves the problem:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Comment: Unfortunately whitelisting is removed in Ubuntu 13.04 !! that command gives `No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel'`